# Replacement in Gradle for Ant's zipfileset

Tags: gradle, groovy, ant

I am trying to migrate Ant targets to Gradle tasks, but I'm having an issue. In Ant, zipfileset allows us to specify a prefix folder to all files inside jar or zip. How can we achieve this in Gradle?

**How can we replace the Ant code below in Gradle?**

```
<jar destfile="${jarDestination}">
  <zipfileset dir="${dir}" prefix="${prefix}"/>
</jar>
```

**Notice:** I know that we can use ant inside Gradle. I seeking for clear gradle/groovy solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
apply plugin: 'java'

def dir = 'src/myJar/resources'
def prefix = 'foo'
File jarDestination = file("$buildDir/myJar/myJar.jar")

task myJar(type: Zip) {
   from dir {
      into prefix
   }
   destinationDir = jarDestination.parent
   archiveName = jarDestination.name
}
assemble.dependsOn myJar
```